# SignalR resolving a hub context from a change event handler

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have an issue where I can't seem to send new data to the connected Signal R clients from a `ChangedEventHandler`. The docs says that I can get the hub context by using:-

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.addToList(insertedCustomer);
```

However nothing gets sent to the clients (checked on fiddler) or any errors reported. My onchange event is wired up at the moment from `Application_Start` as I am creating a proof of concept.  I should point out the hub does work on start up and retrieves the data from the initial `GetAll` call

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        _sqlTableDependency.OnChanged += _sqlTableDependency_OnChanged;
        _sqlTableDependency.Start();
        ...
    }

    private void _sqlTableDependency_OnChanged(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<BiddingText> e)
    {
        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case ChangeType.Insert:
                foreach (var insertedCustomer in e.ChangedEntities)
                {
                    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
                    context.Clients.All.addToList(insertedCustomer);

                    biddingTextList.Add(insertedCustomer);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the hub `context` I get my ChatHub back.

My Javascript code:

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:37185/signalr";

// Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

chat.client.initialText = function(data) {
    var index;
    //console.log(data.length);
    for (index = 0; index < data.List.length; ++index) {
        $('#list').append("<li>" + data.List[index].text + "</li>");
    }
};

chat.client.addToList = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#list').append("<li>" + data.text + "</li>");
};

// Start the connection.
$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
    chat.server.getAll(1831);
});
```

My Hub code:

```
public class ChatHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public ChatHub(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void GetAll(int saleId)
    {
        var model = mediator.Request(new BiddingTextQuery { SaleId = saleId});
        Clients.Caller.initialText(model);
    }

}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but the `Clients.Connection.Identity` is different everytime I use `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some similar issues a while back setting up a Nancy API to publish some events to SignalR clients.

The core issue I had was that I had failed to ensure Nancy and SignalR was using the same DI container at the SignalR global level.

SignalR, as Nancy, has a default `DependencyResolver` that is used to resolve any dependencies in your hubs. When I failed to implement the same source of dependencies for Nancy and SignalR I basically ended up with two separate applications.

Small disclaimer: You have not posted your config code, so my solution here is based on some assumptions (as well as the following twitter answer from David Fowler when you reached out on twitter:

> @rippo you have a custom dependency resolver and global has has another. You need to use one container
>   (https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/635000470340153344)

Now some code:

First you need to implement a custom SignalR depependency resolver, and ensure it uses the same source of dependencies as the rest of your application.

This is the implementation I used for an Autofac container:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Builder;
using Autofac.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;

namespace LabCommunicator.Server.Configuration
{
    internal class AutofacSignalrDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver, IRegistrationSource
    {
        private ILifetimeScope LifetimeScope { get; set; }

        public AutofacSignalrDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            LifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
            var currentRegistrationSource = LifetimeScope.ComponentRegistry.Sources.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetType() == GetType());
            if (currentRegistrationSource != null)
            {
                ((AutofacSignalrDependencyResolver)currentRegistrationSource).LifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
            }
            else
            {
                LifetimeScope.ComponentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(this);
            }
        }

        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            object result;

            if (LifetimeScope == null)
            {
                return base.GetService(serviceType);
            }

            if (LifetimeScope.TryResolve(serviceType, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            object result;

            if (LifetimeScope == null)
            {
                return base.GetServices(serviceType);
            }

            if (LifetimeScope.TryResolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType), out result))
            {
                return (IEnumerable<object>)result;
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<object>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
        {
            var typedService = service as TypedService;
            if (typedService != null)
            {
                var instances = base.GetServices(typedService.ServiceType);

                if (instances != null)
                {
                    return instances
                        .Select(i => RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(i.GetType(), (c, p) => i).As(typedService.ServiceType)
                        .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                        .PreserveExistingDefaults()
                        .CreateRegistration());
                }
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }

        bool IRegistrationSource.IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, in your SignalR config, you need to assign the custom dependency resolver:

Note: My app was using owin, so you may not need the `HubConfiguration` bit, but you need the `GlobalHost` bit (which is the one I messed up when my stuff was not working).

```
 var resolver = new AutofacSignalrDependencyResolver(container);
 'Owin config options. 
 var config = new HubConfiguration()
            {
                Resolver = resolver,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableCrossDomain = true
            };
  GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;
  'More owin stuff      
  app.MapHubs(config);
```

Hope this will help resolve your issue.

Comment: Perfect, I am using `SimpleInjector` and in my case just needed to add  `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;`  Never noticed that in any of the docs! cheers matey, now I owe you

Comment: I remember doing a lot! of research and digging to get to the bottom of this. At the end I believe David Fowler helped me out with the final details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the clients that connect to the hub, and then send them the new messages, something like this

This is a base class I wrote for my Hubs

```
/// <summary>
/// base class for Hubs in the system.
/// </summary>
public class HubBase : Hub  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The hub users
    /// </summary>
    protected static ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, HubUser> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, HubUser>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the connection connects to this hub instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" />
    /// </returns>
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected() {
        Guid userName = RetrieveUserId();
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        HubUser user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new HubUser {
            UserId = userName,
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
        });
        lock (user.ConnectionIds) {
            user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a connection disconnects from this hub gracefully or due to a timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stopCalled">true, if stop was called on the client closing the connection gracefully;
    /// false, if the connection has been lost for longer than the
    /// <see cref="P:Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Configuration.IConfigurationManager.DisconnectTimeout" />.
    /// Timeouts can be caused by clients reconnecting to another SignalR server in scaleout.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" />
    /// </returns>
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) {
        try {
            Guid userName = RetrieveUserId();
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            HubUser user;
            Users.TryGetValue(userName, out user);
            if (user != null) {
                lock (user.ConnectionIds) {
                    user.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));
                    if (!user.ConnectionIds.Any()) {
                        HubUser removedUser;
                        Users.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            //Bug in SignalR causing Context.User.Identity.Name to sometime be null
            //when user disconnects, thus remove the connection manually.
            lock (Users) {
                HubUser entry = Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ConnectionIds.Contains(Context.ConnectionId));
                if (entry != null) entry.ConnectionIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
            }
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    private Guid RetrieveUserId() {
        Cookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket decryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(decryptedCookie.UserData);

        return user.Id;
    }
}
```

Then the Hub code is

```
/// <summary>
/// A hub for sending alerts to users.
/// </summary>
public class AlertHub : HubBase, IAlertHub {
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the alert.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    /// <param name="userId">The user identifier.</param>
    public void SendAlert(string message, Guid userId) {
        HubUser user;
        Users.TryGetValue(userId, out user);
        if (user != null) {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlertHub>();
            context.Clients.Clients(user.ConnectionIds.ToList()).sendAlert(message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send alert to user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="returnId">The return identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="userId">The user identifier.</param>
    public void ReturnProcessedAlert(Guid returnId, Guid userId) {
        HubUser user;
        Users.TryGetValue(userId, out user);
        if (user != null) {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlertHub>();
            context.Clients.Clients(user.ConnectionIds.ToList()).returnProcessedAlert(returnId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though in my case this wasn't my issue this code is going to help me elsewhere. Thanks +1